# How to force the class are not removed when linking?

Tags: android, linker, xamarin.android, release

How to force the class are not removed when linking? I write for Android application in Visual Studio 2015 on the framework, Xamarin. Faced with such a problem: The app works fine in **Debug** mode, but when you put the **Release** mode of the application functionality is lost, ie, Several classes are deleted when linking and when they call, the application crush. Tried both the written documentation Xamarin put before the class is one of the attributes:

```
[Android.Runtime.Preserve]
[Android.Runtime.Preserve (AllMembers = true)]
[Android.Runtime.Preserve (Conditional = true)]
```

did not help. I tried also:

```
#pragma warning disable 0219, 0649
```

It did not help. I tried to use **linkskip**, but it did not help.

The only solution is found, it is in the linker properties indicate **Linker Behavior = Do not Link (None in Visual Studio)** (in **Debug** mode). But this is a bad solution, because suitable for debugging, but not for release. And application size has increased by more than 2.5 times!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what resolved for me was to change the Linker Behavior to **Link SDK assemblies** only and also changing the Xamarin studio channel to Alpha.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but to switch to the alpha channel does not want. I will wait for a stable version, perhaps this bug fix

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a linker.xml file in the project root, as described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/) .  The file should contain all of the types that you want to ensure don't get deleted during linking.  Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="Your.Assembly.Name">
        <type fullname="Fully.Qualified.Type.Name" />
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

Be sure to set the file's Build Action to LinkDescription.

Also, I had a problem where I was including one type but its base class was being deleted during linking.  Be sure to include all of the type's ancestors.

Hope that helps,

Paul